# Oracle SQL- Fetch a particular column based on other two columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
         Table 1    
I_ID    S_id    E_id
1000    1234    123
1002    1235    12
1002    1235    13
1003    3456    234
1004    1256    236
1004    1257    236
1005    1239    236

    Table2  
Desc    SS_id   EE_id
aaaa    1234    125
bbbb    1235    13
cccc    2222    234
hhhh    4444    236
jjjj    1239    236
```

1.First I need to match S_id of table 1 with SS_id of Table 2 and pick the corresponding Desc

2.If the count of S_id in point 1 is greater than 1 then match S_id,E_ID of table 1 with SS_id,EE_ID of Table 2 and pick the corresponding Desc

3.When S_ID of Table 1 is not present in SS_ID of Table2 then match E_id of Table 1with EE_id of Table2 and pick the corresponding Desc

4.if count of E_id in the point 3 is greater than 1 then match S_id,E_ID of table 1 with SS_id ,EE_ID of Table 2 and pick the corresponding Desc

5.Else populate null

```
   Output   
I_ID    Desc
1000    aaaa
1002    bbbb
1003    cccc
1004    null
1005    jjjj
```

can you help me write SQl query

Comment: Where is your query ? What did you try ? We are here to solve your problems not to complete your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your result seem that you need only

```
select table1.I_ID 
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.S_id = table2.SS_id
```

(otherwise try to post an example more appropriate)